# how to include a clickable url in Micropost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

working from the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl

I tried .html_safe that does not seem to work

you can post any url in the micropost but it shows as text only and no link.

```
    <li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= image_tag feed_item.user.avatar.url(:small) %>
    <span class="user">
      <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <span class="content">
    <%= feed_item.content.html_safe %></span>
    <span class="timestamp">
      Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
    </span>
    <div style="float: right; margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;">
    <%= image_tag 'star.png' %><%= image_tag 'retweet.png' %>
    </div>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", feed_item, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: feed_item.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this gem right here https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

After you install the gem, just wrap your Micropost's content like this

```
<%= auto_link(feed_item.content) %>
```

As @joey mentioned in the comment below, for him he had to add this to the Gemfile

```
gem 'rails_autolink', :require => 'rails_autolink'
```

Comment: Thanks! got it working by adding this to Gemfile: `gem 'rails_autolink', :require => 'rails_autolink'`